# Displaying bookings on weekdays

Tags: python, string, flask

I'm writing a booking website (in flask) where I select one week at a time for display.
The display always shows seven days and bookings are pulled from a database. I want to show which days of the week are booked.

The data for a given week can contain between zero and seven rows of data depending on the number of bookings for that week (where a row represents a day of the week that is booked).

**Example**: Suppose Monday and Friday are booked, then I would get a list of 2 rows from querying the database where the first row is for Monday and the second is for Friday.

I want to display that result like this:

```
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
B   F   F   F   B   F   F
```

(where `B` is booked and `F` is free).

**Question**: What is a good way of iterating through the rows returned by the database to obtain a display like this?

Comment: are the db results sorted by day? if so you can just iterate over the days of week and on each check for match in bookings[0] and pop(0) from it if it's same day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an array called `rows_of_data` which contains an element for each day of the week that is booked, you could do something like this:

```
print("Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun")
booked = ['F'] * 7
for row in rows_of_data:
    booked[row.day] = 'B' //assuming row.day is an int in 0..6
print("   ".join(booked))
```

I can tailor this answer to your needs a little bit more if you can give a little more information as to what properties your rows have.

Comment: This looks good. I will chew on it a bit.

Comment: Works nicely in my application.